# iOS - Use 3rd party library in my custom framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I was building my own framework, and I installed a 3rd party lib `BadgeSwift` via `CocoaPods` in my framework. Everything was good before I integrated my framework into a test project.

In my test project, I got this run time error every time I ran it on the simulator:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/BadgeSwift.framework/BadgeSwift
Referenced from: /Users/brian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D2C8A32-ADD7-4D3C-8C3A-0AD696B8B147/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F0B059EB-E004-49B7-92A1-7798CE17B12A/TestIMKit.app/Frameworks/IMKit.framework/IMKit
Reason: image not found
```

I got this error even when I actually didn't use `BadgeSwift` at all. (I tried to remove all my code using `BadgeSwift` while leaving the lib installed)

Also, I am sure `BadgeSwift` is irrelevant. Every 3rd party lib will trigger this run time crash.

How to install 3rd party libraries in my custom framework via `CocoaPods` correctly?

Comment: Did your  "own library" is added in " test project's" -> General -> Embedded Binaries ? If not then add, Clear your Derived Data. Clean and Run Again.

Comment: And regarding 3rd party libraries, If you are using Swift 3.0, Then Those projects must be upgraded to 3.0 Run. And If not, Then you can simply follow the steps of my above comment

Comment: I am facing same problem, @Brian did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

After pulling off my brain for almost 2 days i finally figured out the solution.
All you need to do is set the third party frameworks you are using for e.g:- socket.io-client-swift as Optional instead of Required under Link binary with Libraries in build Phases section. That's all. try it again and it will run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go To :

```
Your Project -> Target -> General -> Embedded Binaries
```

- Add your library in this section.
- Clean Derived Data Folder
- Clean and Run

If you are facing this error in every 3rd party library, Then try using add their framework by following above steps.

Normally it is not required for every 3rd party library.

When we install cocoa-pod, libPods-"Project name".a file of cocoa pod is added in

```
Your Project -> Target -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries
```

So normally it is not required.

Yet if you are facing this issue, If you fix this issue by adding above steps then it will be good, or try to **Re-install CocoaPods**.

Comment: Tried your solution. The result was the same, it did not work ... :(